# Factor $X^7 − 1$ into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}_{127}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

Problem: Factor $X^7 − 1$ into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}_{127} [X]$

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to approach this, and this course topic in general. Any help (or even better, a worked solution) would be great.

I recognise that 127 is a prime number. I'm assuming the use of $2^7 $($=128 \equiv 1 \pmod{127})$ is applicable somewhere.

Edit: thank you for all your comments! And typesetting suggestions

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\mathbb Z_{127}[X]$? Typeset it as `$\mathbb Z_{127}$`.

Comment: Since 2 is a root, the polynomial has the factor $X-2$.

Comment: You can easily check that $x=2^{k} \, , \, 0 \le k \le 6$ denote the $7$ distinct roots of $x^{7}-1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{127}$.

Comment: Another Mathjax suggestion: write $128 \equiv 1 \pmod{127}$  typesetter as `$128 \equiv 1 \pmod{127}$` or $128 \equiv 1 \mod{127}$  typesetter as `$128 \equiv 1 \mod{127}$`.

Comment: $127-1=2×3^2×7$ and so $X^7-1$ has exactly $7$ roots mod $127$, and they are the powers of any solution except $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the seventh roots of unity. In the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_{127}$ they form a cyclic group of order $7$. Because $7$ is prime every element different from the neutral element (which is $1$) will generate the group. Since you've found already another root, namely $2$, you just need to compute the powers of $2$ and get everything. So you have
$$X^7-1 = (X-1)(X-2)(X-4)(X-8)(X-16)(X-32)(X-64).$$